# How to customize Bootstrap in rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with my rails app.
Here is my application.scss

```html
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "colors";
@import "custom";
```

so after importing bootstrap i import custom.scss
Here i have strange behaviour. 
In custom.scss i have:

```html
@import "colors";

.navbar-default {
  background: $primary-color;
  a {
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

So my navbar-default background color is overwritten to my primary-color, but link color is still default. Inspecting in browser i see that my custom style for link is crossed and default is used. Very strange.

Comment: try changing the name of the `custom.scss` to `custom.css.scss`

Comment: @Mukul215, still the same

Comment: Alas, this is my biggest gripe with using bootstrap... overwriting all their super specific CSS styles and following their forced DOM structure. Its gotten to the point that if I'm making something with a design that is going to need more than a little custom styling, I just don't use bootstrap and roll-my-own styles from the ground up. I find that better than having stylesheets that are very messy.

Comment: That's why they provide [a tool to create custom builds](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! :-) I did not know that their tool allows you to set the individual styles on all their components. That seems like it would be really painful to assign all those styles by punching numbers into inputs outside your application though. 

Also, I agree that just using the components that you need definitely reduces the problem, but maintaining those components still suffers from the same fundamental problem. Guess it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @SexyTurnip, how could i use it with Rails 4?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Rails

Comment: If you're into Sass, I'd recommend https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass. If you're more a Less sort of person, check out https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails. These are easy drop-in gems that play nice with the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector used by Bootstrap is this `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a` which is more specific than your selector (`.navbar-default a`) and so it will always take precedent.

Try this...

```
.navbar-default {
  background: $primary-color;

  .navbar-nav {
    >li {
       >a {
          color: $white;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXRVQb)